# What's wrong with this screen capture code?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, screen-capture

I found a screen capture code on here, but when I tried to build it it wouldn't build, so I fixed the code up myself and now it builds but I don't think it works because when debugging VS says that it can't read from hBitmap (no data?). I'm novice programmer so I really have no idea what to do at this point... and I probably didn't fix the code properly...

I appreciate your help.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    // get the device context of the screen
    HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);     
    // and a device context to put it in
    HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

    int x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
    int y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

    // maybe worth checking these are positive values
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);

    // get a new bitmap
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
    // now your image is held in hBitmap. You can save it or do whatever with it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There's nothing wrong.

`hBitmap` contains a handle to a bitmap that has the screencap data retrieved via `BitBlt`. When you hover over `hBitmap` in Visual Studio, it is merely informing you that `hBitmap` is not a valid pointer to memory, which is a correct report- windows handles are just tokens that resolve to structures whose memory location and implementation are managed privately by the windows API.

To demonstrate that your code is indeed pulling something from the screen, try writing it to a file. It is helpful to use GDI+ to write to a file, as it will save you a lot of initialization code that you would have to write by hand.

Here's a quick console app that will emit a PNG file using your code and [a helper function `GetEncoderClsid` to get the PNG encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533843.aspx).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
  UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
  UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

  ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

  GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
  if (size == 0)
    return -1;  // Failure

  pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
  if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
    return -1;  // Failure

  GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

  for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
  {
    if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
    {
      *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
      free(pImageCodecInfo);
      return j;  // Success
    }
  }

  free(pImageCodecInfo);
  return -1;  // Failure
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
  ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
  GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

  // get the device context of the screen
  HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
  // and a device context to put it in
  HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

  int x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
  int y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

  // maybe worth checking these are positive values
  HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);

  // get a new bitmap
  HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

  BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
  // now your image is held in hBitmap. You can save it or do whatever with it

  CLSID pngClsid;
  GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);

  Bitmap *bmp = new Bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);
  bmp->Save(L"desktop_slice.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
  delete bmp;

  GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
  return 0;
}
```

Make sure to add `gdiplus.lib` to your list of source libraries in your project settings. Running this will create a file called "desktop_slice.png" to be emitted.

If you need to do additional work after retrieving the bitmap containing screen data, you should select it into a compatible DC and call additional GDI functions with that DC, or perform other modifications to `hMemoryDC` before swapping out the bitmap with `SelectObject`.

If you need to do lower-level work at the pixel level, you should look at creating a DIB Section with a known pixel format that meets your needs, and working with the pointer returned from the `ppvBits` argument.

[CreateDIBSection @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494.aspx)

Comment: I have a problem, with #include "stdafx.h" (No such file or directory). (I created an empty Win32 project...)

Comment: If I comment stdafx out, I still get a diff error: error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_TCHAR'. if I include tchar.h I get a diff error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: `int main()` is okay for the purposes of exploration instead of `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`, but you should look into compiling under UNICODE, and you're right, "stdafx.h" won't be present if you create an empty Win32 Project (try creating a console project)

Answer (score 1):

Lets see. When you use `SelectObject()` for the first time

```
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);
```

you associate hBitmap with hMemoryDC. You **cannot** delete hBitmap as long hMemoryDC exist! So calling

```
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

does nothing. In order to properly delete hBitmap you use hOldBitmap and you do

```
SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
```

After this you can no longer use hMemoryDC. So erase your last line

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
```

and you should be fine. Release resources when you dont need hMemoryDC anymore.

Edit

The proper way to release hBitmap and hMemoryDC is:

```
SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
hBitmap = NULL;
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
hMemoryDC = NULL;
```

valter

Comment: Sorry you kind of lost me.

Comment: @Tez The first `SelectObject()` makes hMemoryDC from 1x1 to XxY dimensions. The second `SelectObject()` makes hMemoryDC from XxY back to 1x1 so you can not use it.

Comment: So in otherwords, everything is correct, except I just have to delete: hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap); and get the bitmap info from hOldBitmap? What about the bitblt? Is it okay if that comes after hOldBitmap?

Comment: @Tez You want to draw part of the screen or you want to save it as bmp?

Comment: @Tez If you want to use hMemoryDC for drawing delete the second `SelectObject().` If you want to save it as bmp use the following link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I just want to store the picture in memory so I can draw it.

Comment: What's the difference between the hMemoryDC and the hOldBitmap? Which one contains the picture??

Comment: @Tez The image is stored to hBitmap, but because you can not use bitmaps to draw directly, you use a **handle** to this bitmap which is hMemoryDC.hOldBitmap is the original (1x1 monochrome bitmap) which hMemoryDC was pointing to.